# Can I remove the border of VScode markdown code tag style?

Tags: visual-studio-code, styles, markdown

The border around the code tag is annoying, especially if there are many of code tags inside a paragraph. Can I remove it in the VScode editor?

[image: code tag style in vscode]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the reason is I installed the [markdown all in one](https://github.com/yzhang-gh/vscode-markdown) extension and the border was hardcoded for the dark theme.

There is a [issue](https://github.com/yzhang-gh/vscode-markdown/issues/509) talking about the problem and how to tweak it from code.

But for me, the built-in markdown support of VScode just work well.